# How to format numbers using Regular Expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I would need to change the format to `123.456.789.11`, so far I have only managed to do it as shown in the example https://regex101.com/r/sY1nH4/1, but I would need it to always have 3 digits at the beginning, thank you for your help

```bash
$repl = preg_replace('/(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/m', '.', $input);
```

Comment: What format is `$input`?

Comment: Like https://regex101.com/r/sY1nH4/101?

Comment: Why regex? This is easily possible without writing a regex that you will have trouble with decyphering in two weeks. `implode(',', str_split($str, 3))` works just fine

Answer (score 4):

You should assert that it is not the end of the string instead to prevent adding a dot at the end:

```
\d{3}(?!$)\K
```

- `\d{3}` Match 3 digits
- `(?!$)` Negative lookahead, assert not the end of the string to the right
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aYTIHX/1)

```
$re = '/\d{3}(?!$)\K/m';
$str = '111222333444
11222333444';

$result = preg_replace($re, ".", $str);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
111.222.333.444
112.223.334.44
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use this approach, using a capture group:

```php
$input = "12345678911";
$output = preg_replace("/(\d{3})(?=\d)/", "$1.", $input);
echo $output;  // 123.456.789.11
```

The above replaces every 3 numbers, starting from the left, with the same numbers followed by a dot, provided that at least one other digit follows.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution using `\B` (opposite of `\b`):

```bash
\d{3}\B\K
```

Replace it with `.`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D9bmRl/1)

By using `\B` after 3 digits we ensure that we don't match the last position.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a regular expression actually. split into equal parts, join with comma:

```php
$formatted = implode(',', str_split($str, 3));
```